# TOR + Python + Tweepy or +Twyhton

Tags: python, tor

I can use python + Tweepy or + twitter -tools or + Twyhton and go through the TOR network?
To share any link or tutorial that explains how to do ?

If I use Tails from the console and throw my script python + tweepy for example, I can consider my location be through TOR ?

Thank you very much

Comment: You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516356/how-update-my-twitter-status-with-python-over-tor-and-change-my-identity) answer helpful on how to go through Tor.

Comment: Sorry 've doubled my question tailored to satisfy guests have not received a clear answer to my question , I'll erase the previous one, thanks